# How do I save to localStorage dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I want to have a score system on each news article. Kind of like reddit actually where you can upvote and downvote each post. Right now I have the scores changing dynamically by clicking on the buttons. Now, how can I save all the different scores to localStorage dynamically, or would it be better to store it in like a database?

```
import React from "react";

    import Up from "./UpDown/Up";
    import Down from "./UpDown/Down";

    export default class Vote extends React.Component {

        constructor(){
            super();
            this.state =  {
                score: 0, 
                voted: 0, 
                imgup: "img/upvote.png", 
                imgdown: "img/downvote.png",
                ident: 0
            };
        }

        saveStorage(key, val) {
            localStorage.setItem(key, val);
        } 

        handleChangeUp(){

            // ===========================skip this part
            const {voted, score, imgup, imgdown, ident} = this.state;
            var x = this.state.score;

            if (!voted) {
                this.setState({voted: 1, score: x+=1, imgup: "img/upvote-clicked.png"});
            }
            else if(Math.abs(voted)){
                if (voted == 1){
                    this.setState({voted: 0, score: x-=1, imgup: "img/upvote.png"});
                }
                else if (voted == -1){
                    this.setState({voted: 1, score: x+=2, imgup: "img/upvote-clicked.png", imgdown: "img/downvote.png"});
                }
            }
            //===============================
            x = this.state.score;
            this.saveStorage(ident, x);
        }

        handleChangeDown(){

            //================================skip this part
            const {voted, score, imgup, imgdown, ident} = this.state;
            var x = this.state.score;

            if (!voted) {
                this.setState({voted: -1, score: x-=1, imgdown: "img/downvote-clicked.png"});
            }
            else if(Math.abs(voted)){
                if (voted == 1){
                    this.setState({voted: -1, score: x-=2, imgup: "img/upvote.png", imgdown: "img/downvote-clicked.png"});
                }
                else if (voted == -1){
                    this.setState({voted: 0, score: x+=1, imgdown: "img/downvote.png"});
                }
            }
            //==============================================
            x = this.state.score;
            this.saveStorage(ident, x);
        }

        render(){
            const vote = {fontFamily: "'Hack', 'Arial'", fontSize: "13px", textAlign: "center", margin: "auto", marginTop: "0px", marginBottom: "0px", color: "#4d4d4d", fontWeight: "700"};
            const pos = {width: "35px", marginLeft: "2px", marginRight: "2px"}

            const { score, imgup, imgdown } = this.state;
            var { id } = this.props;

            return(

                <div class="col-xs-2 " style={pos} >
                    <div class="row ">

                        <div onClick={this.handleChangeUp.bind(this)} style={{cursor: "pointer"}}>
                            <Up imgURL = {imgup} />
                        </div>

                        <div style={vote}>
                            {score}
                        </div>

                        <div onClick={this.handleChangeDown.bind(this)} style={{cursor: "pointer"}}>
                            <Down imgURL = {imgdown} />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>          
            );
        }
    }
```

The problem I have right now is I don't know how to pass the this.props.id into the handleChangUp and handleChangeDown function. So no matter which articles I press the key is always 0 as it is the default val. And the stored score is delayed by 1 click.

So when I press upvote, it displays 1 on the site, but stores a 0. If I uncheck that upvote it will undo upvote and display 0 on the site, but stores a 1.

Also, please do give me advice on the code itself, I know it's a complete mess and there's probably a way more efficent way to do what I'm doing.

Thanks

Comment: How will the page know other people's votes when you are going to use localStorage? Also, localStorage is removed when, for example, the user clears his browsing history.

Comment: Huh I have not thought this through... Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a database. LocalStorage is intended for the local machine. LocalStorage will provide you with no way to obtain the entirety of the votes across all clients.

It also goes away the moment the user clears browser cache. Its great to use LocalStorage when you need to store data between views/page changes without having to make an API call (makes sites feel faster) - but it is not intended to be used in the way you desire.